# How to set "Health Check Path"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, health-monitoring

### Update 12/21/2017 - 2 p.m.

It was really a bug. AWS corrected it. I still don't know what is the correct value though. I managed to set `/health` but the instance is always unhealthy since. Any advice?

### Original 12/21/2017 - 8 a.m.

Today AWS Elastic Beanstalk web console got an update for Configuration in our region. In the old GUI, we were asked to set the *health check **url***. So we input `https://domain/health`.

In the new GUI, AWS is asking for *health check **path***. But no matter what value I try, I cannot save the config and I always receive the same result:

[image]

I tried these values:

- /
- health
- /health
- HTTPS:443/health
- HTTPS/health
- https:443/health
- https/health
- HTTP:80/health
- HTTP/health
- http:80/health
- http/health

I believe it is a bug, isn't? Have you been successful setting the health path?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: @klemens It started to work all of a sudden with `/health`. Maybe it was a temporary bug on Amazon side...?

Comment: Hey, see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=281280&tstart=0 - looks like they found the bug.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a raw html file with "OK" inside and redirect your health path to this html file.
If you use Django, just do:

views.py

```
def health(request):
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^health/', views.health, name='health'),
```

Answer (score 0):

From the forum post linked by Klemens, what worked for me was setting the health check url to `/`, saving+applying changes, then going back and putting my real health check URL back in.